# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

so it's been 4 days now that Tomcat won't launch for some reason, tried everything i could but Nothing really worked for me, one of the errors i'm getting is as mentionned in the title, but i'm have a lot more than those (here is the full error log [Apache TomCat failed to start lifecycle exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693346/apache-tomcat-failed-to-start-lifecycle-exception))

So first i thought i didn't have the class ServiceRegistry but i do have it [As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3JBO.png)

**UPDATE**
So i added hibernate core into the lib folder Under apache tomcat installation and the server started again, but it's not mapping my servlets for some reason

**UPDATE 2 **
I  copied ojdbc6.jar and hibernate -core into the lib folder of tomcat and now it works fine
Thanks for your help lads.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281326/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-service-serviceregistry (and some others that essentially say the same thing). are you sure the hibernate core jar actually gets deployed? There may be an issue with your pom file.

Comment: the thing is that i'm not using maven so i think it has Nothing to do with the pom, i thought it was maybe jar files missing but i'm pretty sure i got everything

Comment: Have a look inside the generated war, the hibernate core jar should be present.

Comment: Since i'm a complete newbie to web application, can you tell me how to do that ? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281326/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-service-serviceregistry)

Comment: Great, but that makes your question - as I thought - a duplicate of a couple of others here on SO. But anyways, good to hear you solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the ojdbc.6 (for oracle 11g users) and hibernate -core.jar file into the lib folder of the apache tomcat installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

If someone got this problem using maven, just put the scope of dependencies as "compile"